# Laravel interface DI binding issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dependency-injection

So basically I made some services and of course I wanted to cache my data processing using the decorator pattern:

CampaignService:

```
public function __construct(
    CampaignDAO $campaignDao,
    BidServiceInterface $bidService, //notice the interface, here I want to inject the decorated service
    ItemService $itemService
){
    $this->campaignDao = $campaignDao;
    $this->bidService = $bidService;
    $this->itemService = $itemService;
}
```

CampaignServiceDecorator:

```
public function __construct(CampaignService $campaignService) //auto-inject
{
    $this->decorated = $campaignService;
}
```

BidService:

```
public function __construct(BidDao $bidDao)//auto-inject
{
    $this->bidDao = $bidDao;
}
```

BidServiceDecorator:

```
public function __construct(BidService $bidService)//auto-inject
{
    $this->decorated = $bidService;
}
```

I get the following, understandable at first, exception:

> [Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException]   Target
>   [App\Services\Interfaces\BidServiceInterface] is not instantiable
>   while building [App\Services\Decorators\CampaignServiceDecorator,
>   App\Services\CampaignService].

Ok, so I made an explicit bind (in `AppServiceProvider.php` in the `boot()` method) by defining the following (first bind definition):

```
$this->app->when(CampaignService::class)
    ->needs(BidServiceInterface::class)
    ->give(BidServiceDecorator::class);
[...]
$this->app->bind(BidServiceInterface::class, BidServiceDecorator::class);
```

But I still get the mentioned exception, my autoloader is up to date as well...

Basically I want my `BidService` to have the **decorated service** rather than the raw implementation.

As you can see there is no circular dependency and at this point I'm stuck

P.S: I have also tried the following commands:

`composer dump-autoload`

`php artisan package:discover`

`php artisan clear-compiled`

`php artisan config:clear`

The only solution would be to explicit inject `BidServiceDecorator` in `CampaignService`'s constructor but this is not flexible

Comment: what is the purpose of the first conditional binding when the next line does the same thing?

Comment: I thought since the exception was raised when building `CampaignService` I tried to explicit bind (in addition to the general bind below), was worth a shot...but in vain...

Comment: where did you put your bind definition?

Comment: Updated question: in AppServiceProvider.php in the boot() method